# Custom cell labels only showing when row is selectd

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboard

I'm building an iPhone app using swift with XCode6. I'm running into an issue where the labels I added to the cell only show when the cell row is selected. When the labels are moved outside the cells content view (e.g to the the nav bar) the labels appear. The default textLabel shows up fine, whether or not the row is selected.

Here's an imgur with screenshots of interface builder + actual behavior. https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNQW0.jpg

Code that defines the three non-static labels in custom cell class

```
  @IBOutlet  var posLabel: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet  var hrLabel: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet  var avgLabel: UILabel!
```

Code that sets label text

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as PlayerSelectTableViewCell

    let name = playerNames[indexPath.row]
    var hrs = Int(RosterStore.sharedInstance.get(name).stats["HR"]!)
    var avg = RosterStore.sharedInstance.get(name).stats["AVG"]!
    var avgString = "\(avg)" as NSString
    cell.hrLabel!.text = "\(hrs)"
    cell.posLabel!.text = RosterStore.sharedInstance.get(name).pos
    cell.avgLabel!.text = avgString.substringFromIndex(1)

    cell.textLabel!.text = name

    println(cell.hrLabel.text)
    return cell
}
```

Note that I can set cell.textLabel this way and it works. If it helps, textLabel is highlighted blue, while all the other labels are highlighted green.

Link to github here - https://github.com/klinskyc/OuttaHere
Thanks!

Comment: go ahead and post your code

Comment: Have you set the custom class of your prototype cell correctly in Interface Builder?  Have you connected the labels in your prototype cell to the IBOutlets?

Comment: @Paulw11 My custom class is set. The IBOutlet code is from ctrl dragging the labels themselves into the custom class. I'm able to correctly set and get the label values. They just only show when the row is selected. I want them to show always (like the default textLabel)

Comment: Do you have any code in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` ?

Comment: I am not overriding didSelectRow. It does not exist in my custom table view class.

Comment: hmm, your code snipper looks good.  Are you willing to post the project to github?

Comment: Happy to. https://github.com/klinskyc/OuttaHere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, thanks for posting on github.  I gotcha covered now.  The issue is with this statement:

```
cell.textLabel!.text = name
```

You are calling a text label of size you do not control over the top of everything.  It has transparency when highlighted.  Instead add another UILabel to your `PlayerSelectTableViewCell` class.

Code:

```
import UIKit

class PlayerSelectTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet  var posLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet  var hrLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet  var avgLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!  //new code here
}
```

Drop out the init and nib code from that class - not needed.

Back in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function:

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as PlayerSelectTableViewCell

        let name = playerNames[indexPath.row]
        var hrs = Int(RosterStore.sharedInstance.get(name).stats["HR"]!)
        var avg = RosterStore.sharedInstance.get(name).stats["AVG"]!
        var avgString = "\(avg)" as NSString
        cell.hrLabel!.text = "\(hrs)"
        cell.posLabel!.text = RosterStore.sharedInstance.get(name).pos
        cell.avgLabel!.text = avgString.substringFromIndex(1)
        cell.nameLabel!.text = name  //new code here
                return cell
    }
```

Comment: That would do it. Thanks so much!

Comment: Took me a gzillion hours to figure this out. Thank you. But, I don't quite understand why this code works. Could you please give an explanation?